# Default a Null Value on DataBind

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am binding a nullable boolean column to a CheckBox.
How can I default the checkbox to checked if the column is null, but keep the true/false value if one exists?

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="boolCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("MyBoolColumn") %>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike Eval apparently you can't do much with Bind, other than use a string format:

`Bind("MyColumn", "{0:c}"))`

The solution I found was to use the ItemCreated event

```
        protected void myListView_OnItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.InsertItem)
        {
            ((CheckBox)((ListView)sender).InsertItem.FindControl("MyCheckBox")).Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="boolCheckBox" runat="server" "<%# (Bind("MyBoolColumn") == null? "Checked='checked'" : null %>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but give it a shot:

```
<%# If(Bind("MyBoolColumn") Is Nothing, True, Bind("MyBoolColumn")) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do at database level. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
MyBooleanColumn = 
Case 
When MyBooleanColumn Is Null Then 1 
Else MyBooleanColumn End
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: True, but usually doing something like this at the db level to affect a UI concern creates other issues.  Better to evaluate it closer to its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property with only a getter to your model:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public bool? MyBoolColumn { get; set; }
    public bool MyBoolColumnChecked
    {
        get { return MyBoolColumn ?? true; }
    }
}
```

Then bind to the new property

```
Checked='<%# Bind("MyBoolColumnChecked") %>'
```